# Pass down dependancy from parent project to sub projects (CMake)

Tags: c++, build, cmake

I have a large project that I divide into sub projects (different repos):

[image]

In the picture, A is the main project, it requires C and D. C and D requires B.

When working on C or D seperately an individual copy of B is needed. But when working on A, instead of C or D having their individual copy of B i would like to instead pass down the dependancy on B from A. Or maybe somehow require (from the perspective of C or D) that the client (A) has a copy of B that they use and omit their individual copy.

To make it a bit clearer my use case is a game engine. (A) would be the main project where everything is tied together, (D) would perhaps be the collision engine and (C) a rendering engine. Both rendering and collision share a dependancy on a vector math library (B).

I am currently looking into CMake but I can not find specifically what I want to accomplish in their documentation.

Is this possible or do you think im subdividing my project too much?

Comment: In `A`, before calling `add_subdirectory(C)` you may define some variable, which contains the dependency. At the beginning of `C` you may check that variable: if variable exists (non-empty), assume it to be `B` dependency; otherwise create separate copy of `B`. Instead of the variable you may use a *target* created in `B`.

Comment: Add simple `if(TARGET B) add_subdirectory(B) endif()` to both CMakeLists.txt inside `D` and `C`. It will pick the first dir

Comment: There is nothing really complicated in this setup. You can even write a script in cmake to git clone the B repo when needed. The problems will arise if you need a different configuration of B for C or D or A projects - but if you need the same B project for them all, this is really simple to do,  with a simple variable check or a single `if`.

Comment: @Tsyvarev Alright thanks that makes sense

Comment: @KamilCuk Alright i see, something like that would do it. Thank you